# Fastest way to mask raster using points

Tags: r, raster

I have a very large `rasterbrick` and some coordinates held in a different object. I wish to use the points as a mask, returning NA for all cells *except* where my points are located (for my particular application I need to preserve the extent, resolution and origin of the input `rasterbrick`).

I can accomplish this with the following:

```
library(raster)
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)

# Load a rasterbrick
b <- brick(system.file("external/rlogo.grd", package="raster"))

# Create some random points as test points for masking
pts<-as_tibble(rasterToPoints(b[[1]])) %>% 
  select(x, y) %>% 
  sample_n(15, replace = TRUE)

plot(b[[1]])
points(pts)

# Convert points to SpatialPoints so they can be passed to `mask`
pts <- st_as_sf(x = pts, coords = c("x", "y"),
                crs = crs(b))

# Mask stack using pts
xx<-raster::mask(b, pts)
plot(xx)
```

In this example, the code executes very quickly but when scaling this up, it can take a long time to run. What would be a more efficient way of doing this for a large, multi-layer `rasterbrick`? For a sense of scale, my `rasterbrick's are`360, 720, 259200, 3653 (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)` so it would be great to speed things along.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a lot of layers.

Your code (with some simplification)

```
library(raster)
b <- brick(system.file("external/rlogo.grd", package="raster"))
set.seed(1)
pts <- sampleRandom(b, 10, sp=TRUE)
xx <- raster::mask(b, pts)
```

Two alternatives, I do not know if they are faster.

Alternative 1

```
y <- rasterize(pts, b, 1)
m <- mask(b, y)
```

Alternative 2

```
v <- extract(b, pts)
r <- rasterize(pts, b, v)
```

Comment: Thanks Robert. Yes, I wish these rasters weren't so large but I'm handling ISIMIP daily climate data; each stack is daily climate data for a decade (at a global extent), hence the extremely large sizes. I wanted to basically "throw away" all the data I don't need across the globe, except for some randomly selected points that I already have. I assumed masking would allow me to do this, but perhaps it's not the best approach.

Comment: Accepting this answer for now; while I don't think either solutions are faster, they do provide alternative solutions to my original question.